# Save Image in NFC reader in Android

Tags: android, nfc

What should I do if I want to save / insert image into smartcard using Android aplication?

My smartcard mode is "mifare desfire ev1 4k".

Comment: Please show some code from your application so we can help add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you'll need to perform your desired operation:

1. Authenticate with the DESFire card
2. Create an Application that will store your file
3. Select your application
4. Authenticate with your new application
5. Create a standard data file that is at least the size of the image you want to save
6. Write the image bytes to the created file

The DESFire is one of the most complex smartcards on the market and you will need to get a NDA agreement with NXP to learn how the actual commands work.  If your purpose is just to learn how to write to an image to a smartcard using an android phone, you may want to start with a Mifare Classic 4K, if your phone supports it.